# How do I find the minimum/maximum values to use with Root Solvers?

Tags: java, math

I want to use the [root solvers](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/analysis.html) (ex: BrentSolver) in Commons Math to find roots for polynomial functions, but they all seem to require using an initial estimate for minimum/maximum, where the function has different signals.

So how do I go about doing this? I know I can compute f(x) for points inside whatever interval I have in mind, but if my Interval is too big, do I still do that? How big should the step be between every attempt? Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's no guarantee that even order polynomials have (real) roots. If the polynomial is odd, then eventually the polynomial value is dominated by the highest-order term, which has opposite sign for positive and negative values of x. That means that you can pick a large value X and use (-X, +X) as your search interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [Durand-Kerner-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand-Kerner_method) method as an estimate or check. A Java implementation is shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/polyroots).

Answer (score 1):

I think what they want is a starting interval to search in.  The min and max values define the region where you think the roots are.

I don't know what you mean by "interval too big".  It won't be +/- infinity; you must have some region of interest to start with.

Run it once; see what you get.  Try a few other intervals to see if you can find a true global min/max.

It's not possible to use numerical methods as a complete black box.  You have to know something about your function and how the methods work.  Use them as an iterative tool to learn something about your function of interest.